# UIView hirarchy in UIViewController - Iterface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` with to many `UIView`s that contains a lot of elements. The problem is that i cant see behind the front `UIView` and i need to work on the other `UIView`s which is very difficult. What is needed is a way to separate the `UIView`s inside the `UIViewController` to be outside of it and be able to work with them more easily.

I thought about creating a `UIViewController` for each `UIView` and add a container in the main `UIViewController` for each `UIView`, then simply do

```
self.containerView.addSubview(mySubview)
mySubview.frame = self.containerView.frame
```

The problem is, if i want logic for the view, i need to keep a reference to the `UIViewController` holding it.

Second option is to create a xib for each UIView and do the same.

i prefer working with storyboards

Comment: Assuming you are using constraints to size/position your views, temporarily change a constant - such as for the Leading constraint - to a large enough number to "move the view away" while you work on other views. Just remember to change the constant back to where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using storyboard then it should be easy for you to go with xib file as you say in your question, I suggest you using xib file for each of your views, and every logic related to changing specific view should be handled in that view(or you can use view model for you'r views) that can be easily manageable.

don't forget to make public api for each of your xib views that your controller can tell your views to change their state based on your model.

at last you can add your xib views to your storyboard controller and make outlet for them.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use all of your view in one xib such as the below pic:

just set frame or constraint in your code.

[image]

for all view you define you must set this property:

size -> freeform

[image]